# Sudo is not owned by root on a fresh install of 14.04 on a VPS. Huh?

Tags: server, sudo, root, vps

Sudo is not owned by root on a fresh install of 14.04 on a VPS.
Not familiar with this stuff. So why, what does it all mean and what can I do about it?

Steps are:

1. From the VPS management web pages do 'Operating System Reload'
   selecting Ubuntu 14.04
2. Login as root
3. Make a new user and add to sudo

   ```
   adduser demo
   adduser demo sudo
   ```
4. Start a new session login as demo
5. Try to do something useful with sudo

   ```
   sudo apt-get update  
   sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
   ```

Can't figure out why sudo is not working

6. Look at sudo

   ```
   ls -l /usr/bin/sudo  
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 840 839 156708 Feb 10  2014 /usr/bin/sudo
   ```

Not owned by root and no setuid bit set.

Tried changing with chown and chmod but seems like thats just the first step into a world of pain with no exit.

So, what is really going on? It this a VPS issue?

Comment: login as root and run adduser username sudo , alternatively check [Askubuntu  Thread: Sudo command not working.] ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226250

Comment: Thanks. I've tried adding users, no good. Also looked at those too threads but changing file ownership and permissions just seemed to move the problem around. I really want to understand why fresh install is not working the way I understand it should

Comment: cant tell you that because i dont know. Your hosting provider likely uses premade OpenVZ or KVM templates, often the hosting provider use public openvz templates, just a hint. Anyways, i guess somebody else here has a better answer thus i posted in the comment section.

Comment: I'm going to try some other versions/distros see if the results are different. Thanks again.

Comment: Is `pkexec` owned by root and setuid? What about other files in `/usr/bin`?